# Programmatically Toggle a Python PyQt QPushbutton

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Is it possible to programmatically toggle a `QPushButton`? I have a checkable `QPushButton` that a user presses to start a process. When the process is done, how can the button's state be changed to unchecked?

```
runBtn = QPushButton('Run')
runBtn.setCheckable(True)
runBtn.clicked.connect(runProcess)

def runProcess():
    time.sleep(5)
    runBtn.uncheck()    # how should this be done?
```

Comment: Title "*Programmatically Toggle a Python PyQt QPushbutton*" is not accurate, and should be "*Programmatically Release a Python PyQt QPushbutton*". To toggle it there is inherited `QAbstractButton.toggle()` (and the associated/separate signal `toggled`)

Answer (score 4):

this should to the trick.

```
runBtn.setChecked(False)
```

although that's not ideal behaviour.  toggle buttons should be used for turning things on and off, not indicating that something is in progress.  if something is taking time you should change the cursor to a wait cursor and better still show a progress bar/dialog.

Answer (score 2):

It should just be a matter of calling `runBtn.setChecked(False)` once your function has finished running.

As @hluk points out in the comment on this answer, anything that takes a long time to do will block the interface and isn't really a great idea. It would be better to split it off into a thread in that case. This is probably means a lot more learning on your part, but could be worth it in the long run. Anyway, should you decide to go the thread route, you might also want to use `setEnabled(bool)` to disable user input through the button while the thread is running.

Comment: The work you do in that section shouldn't take too much time, otherwise the GUI thread is blocked -- application won't be responsive and GUI won't be redrawn. You should do anything more expensive in different thread and communicate using signals/slots with the GUI thread.

Comment: @hluk: You are of course correct! I've become too used to doing multithreaded stuff all the time myself that I forgot that isn't the case here. I'll update my response!

Comment: Threads won't offer any benefit if the time-consuming task is CPU-bound (because of python's GIL) - multiprocessing would be needed for that.

Comment: Its a Run button that the user presses to run a process in a thread. Clicking the button again should halt the process. Will a toggle button still be suitable in this case? I suppose clicking this button when in the checked state can send a signal to the running thread to do a `QThread::quit()`?

Comment: @ekhumoro: threads don't offer a speed benefit, but they do mean the GUI will be responsive during the time consuming task.

Comment: @Nyxynyx: in that case you need to check the state of the button in `runBtn` and launch or kill the thread accordingly. You case use `runBtn.checked()` to get the button state.

Comment: @three_pineapples. No - it's got nothing to do with speed. In python, if the task is CPU-bound (as opposed to IO-bound) the GUI will still block if threads are used. CPU-bound tasks must be run in a separate process in order to avoid issues with python's GIL.

Comment: @ekhumoro: What you said is true only if your thread is running a single CPU bound task. Most things don't hold the GIL continuously. Even a list comprehension that takes 6 seconds to evaluate doesn't hold the GIL. Unless you are using a poorly written C library, chances are your thread is not holding the GIL for the whole time it is running. In most use cases, the Python interpreter switches between threads often, which is precisely why complex threading examples have locks for specific bits of data so that they don't get modified by a thread half way through the execution of another thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QpushButton and style sheet with it. here is code

```
if(process==running):
     button.setStyleSheet(ENABLE_STYLESHEET )
else
     button.setStyleSheet(DISABLE_STYLESHEET )
```

and you can define the style sheets as below

```
ENABLE_STYLESHEET = """
    QPushButton {
        border: 1px solid #007a94;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color: #007a94;
        min-width: 80px;
        }
    QPushButton:pressed {
        background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                  stop: 0 #008aa6, stop: 1 #008aa6);
        }

    QPushButton:flat {
        border: none;
        }
"""    
DISABLE_STYLESHEET = """
    QPushButton {
       border: 1px solid #808080;
       border-radius: 6px;
       color:#ffffff;
       background-color: #808080;
       min-width: 80px;
       }
   QPushButton:flat {
       border: none;
       }

"""
```

[image: Enable Button]
[image: Disable Button]