# Detect when no buttons are being pushed PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a GUI that is controlling a device over USB. 
The way I have it set up is with basically two buttons, forward and back, and while the button is pressed that function is transmitted to the motor, when the button is released, the off signal is triggered once.

```
    def on_release():
        print('Off')
        self.off()

    def on_click():
        print('forward')
        self.forward()
    button = QPushButton('Cut', self)
    button.move(100,70) 
    button.pressed.connect(on_click)
    button.released.connect(on_release)

    def on_click():
        print('back')
        self.back()
    button = QPushButton('back', self)
    button.move(200,70) 
    button.pressed.connect(on_click)
    button.released.connect(on_release)
```

I've recently encountered an interesting failure mode where if the USB connection is paused (in my case I was using GDB and hit a breakpoint, released the button, then released the breakpoint) at the moment the button is released, the kill signal is never sent and the motor will continue going back or forward forever. (It can be killed by either clicking one of back or forward and releasing, or by killing USB entirely")

I already have protections in place (a threaded heartbeat signal) for turning off the motor in the condition that a USB connection is severed but I'd like to make this fail a little more safely in case that one particular USB off transmission were to fail.

Is there a way for me to check if no buttons are pressed so I can use this to trigger the off signal?

Comment: check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508450/programmatically-toggle-a-python-pyqt-qpushbutton] or perhaps use arduino with a trinamic 2120+ stepper driver. Signal drops == motor stops mode, overload etc. on board. [http://www.watterott.com/de/SilentStepStick]

Comment: you could define the steps your button gives via the usb or stepperdriver when pressing. For example, button1 = 100 steps per pressed event. Button2 = 10 steps, button 3 = 1 step... which in the latter case means you need to press it continiously to keep proceeding. If released... 1 additional step is done and then the stop signal is automatically transmitted (within the stepperdriver or your pyscript).

Comment: another very usefull link is [http://zapmaker.org/projects/grbl-controller-3-0/] where they show how to make a qt gui for arduino board controling a 3d printer. Here [http://zapmaker.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mac.png] shows the 1 step size for moving left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Learning material from tjmarkham **stepper.py** script at [https://github.com/tjmarkham/python-stepper] for a raspberry Pi which can be put behind your buttons:

```
#CURRENT APPLICATION INFO
#200 steps/rev
#12V, 350mA
#Big Easy driver = 1/16 microstep mode
#Turn a 200 step motor left one full revolution: 3200

from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as gpio #https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO
#import exitHandler #uncomment this and line 58 if using exitHandler

class stepper:
    #instantiate stepper 
    #pins = [stepPin, directionPin, enablePin]
    def __init__(self, pins):
        #setup pins
        self.pins = pins
        self.stepPin = self.pins[0]
        self.directionPin = self.pins[1]
        self.enablePin = self.pins[2]

        #use the broadcom layout for the gpio
        gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)

        #set gpio pins
        gpio.setup(self.stepPin, gpio.OUT)
        gpio.setup(self.directionPin, gpio.OUT)
        gpio.setup(self.enablePin, gpio.OUT)

        #set enable to high (i.e. power is NOT going to the motor)
        gpio.output(self.enablePin, True)

        print("Stepper initialized (step=" + self.stepPin + ", direction=" + self.directionPin + ", enable=" + self.enablePin + ")")

    #clears GPIO settings
    def cleanGPIO(self):
        gpio.cleanup()

    #step the motor
    # steps = number of steps to take
    # dir = direction stepper will move
    # speed = defines the denominator in the waitTime equation: waitTime = 0.000001/speed. As "speed" is increased, the waitTime between steps is lowered
# stayOn = defines whether or not stepper should stay "on" or not. If stepper will need to receive a new step command immediately, this should be set to "True." Otherwise, it should remain at "False."

    def step(self, steps, dir, speed=1, stayOn=False):
        #set enable to low (i.e. power IS going to the motor)
        gpio.output(self.enablePin, False)

        #set the output to true for left and false for right
        turnLeft = True
        if (dir == 'right'):
            turnLeft = False;
        elif (dir != 'left'):
            print("STEPPER ERROR: no direction supplied")
            return False
        gpio.output(self.directionPin, turnLeft)

        stepCounter = 0

        waitTime = 0.000001/speed #waitTime controls speed

        while stepCounter < steps:
            #gracefully exit if ctr-c is pressed
            #exitHandler.exitPoint(True) #exitHandler.exitPoint(True, cleanGPIO)

            #turning the gpio on and off tells the easy driver to take one step
            gpio.output(self.stepPin, True)
            gpio.output(self.stepPin, False)
            stepCounter += 1

            #wait before taking the next step thus controlling rotation speed
            sleep(waitTime)

        if (stayOn == False):
            #set enable to high (i.e. power is NOT going to the motor)
            gpio.output(self.enablePin, True)

print("stepperDriver complete (turned " + dir + " " + str(steps) + " steps)")
```

**teststepper.py**:

```
from Stepper import Stepper

#stepper variables
#[stepPin, directionPin, enablePin]
testStepper = Stepper([22, 17, 23])

#test stepper
testStepper.step(3200, "right"); #steps, dir, speed, stayOn
```